# How to know why I lost one or more badges (and which one)?

Tags: feature-request, badges, notifications

I have noticed to have one bronze badge less than some days ago, but I can't see any notification about it. So, I don't know when it happened and what badge I've lost lately.

Is there a way to get some information about the lost badges other than knowing their exact amount by heart and checking the differences from time to time?

Something like a "-1" in the badge tab.

Comment: This happens only in stack overflow and already been discussed in meta stack overflow. They are the documentation badges

Comment: @OptimusPrime not really, tag badges can be lost anywhere.

Comment: @ShadowWizard yes. but it started few hours ago. there are 3-4 posts on MSO raised regarding this

Comment: @OptimusPrime so? The question here is a feature request asking to add a live counter to the badges tab, showing when badges are earned or lost. It's totally legit request, and totally generic. It fits all sites. It doesn't really matter what led the user to ask for this feature.

Comment: retracted cv. read only the title and assumed this was that issue. neeed moar coffee

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably lost Documentation badge(s), as mentioned in [Sunsetting Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation):

> We also have a longstanding policy against revoking badges. But we've never had a badge set for a discontinued beta feature either. While we could just retire them, it seems confusing to show expired Documentation features on the list of badges. In addition, we'd lose a lot of good names for potential future badges. As a compromise, anyone who earned a Documentation badge other than Educated (for reading the tour) will be issued a newly minted silver Documentation Beta badge.

And indeed, you [got the silver badge instead](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/7358/documentation-user?userid=2425452).

That said, I really don't see any reason to complicate the system by adding a live counter when you earn or lose badges. Unlike reputation, they are gained only once in a while, and lost only in very rare situations.

Comment: Yes that's probably what happened, but I think it would be useful to have a live counter for lost badges, equivalent to the one for earned ones (already active).

Comment: @Andrea, there's no point in adding a counter for a one-time event.  Occasionally someone will lose a tag badge for no longer meeting the criteria, but other than that, this is the *only time* that badges have been removed from peoples' accounts.

Comment: @Mark, honestly I didn't know that one can lose a badge only for one-time events, but I think the importance to have a notification about an event it's not strictly connected to its frequency or probability.

Comment: @Andrea so in those rare cases you ask in meta and get a response, as you did here. :)